# Cannot POST error on form submit with nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, passport-local

I am using the following stack :

- React
- PassportJS
- NodeJS
- Express and express-session
- create-react-app with webpack dev server proxying API requests to my node server as mentioned in this [article](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/)

When I do a form submit, I get an error Cannot POST however when I submit to the SAME url using POSTMAN or curl XPOST, I get results. Here is my server.js code :

```
'use strict';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const passport = require('passport')
const initPassport = require('./passport/init');
const session = require('express-session')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const configDB = require('./config/database.js');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var flash = require('connect-flash');

//Connect to mongo
mongoose.connect(configDB.url, {
  useMongoClient: true
}).then(() => console.log('connection with database succeeded'))
.catch(err => console.error(err));


// Initialize Passport
initPassport(passport);

// Serve static assets
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));


//use cookie parser to store data
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ 
  secret: 'mysecret',
  store : new MongoStore ({
    db : mongoose.connection.db,
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    port : '27017',
    url : configDB.url
  }),
  maxAge : 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
})); // session secret

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/signup'
}));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

Form PAGE :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import constants from 'constants/AuthPageConstants';

class RegisterForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="tab-pane fade in" id="basic-tab2">
                <form action="/signup" method="POST">
                    <div className="text-center">
                        <div className="icon-object border-success text-success"><i className="icon-plus3"></i></div>
                        <h5 className="content-group">{constants.register_form_title} <small className="display-block">{constants.register_form_subtitle}</small></h5>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                        <input type="text" name="username" className="form-control" placeholder={constants.register_username_placeholder} />
                        <div className="form-control-feedback">
                            <i className="icon-user-check text-muted"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                        <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" placeholder={constants.register_password_placeholder} />
                        <div className="form-control-feedback">
                            <i className="icon-user-lock text-muted"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                        <input type="text" name="email" className="form-control" placeholder={constants.register_email_placeholder} />
                        <div className="form-control-feedback">
                            <i className="icon-mention text-muted"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="content-divider text-muted form-group"><span>Additions</span></div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" className="styled" />
                                {constants.tos_txt.substring(0, constants.tos_txt.indexOf(" "))} <a href="#">{constants.tos_txt.substr(constants.tos_txt.indexOf(" ") + 1)}</a>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn bg-indigo-400 btn-block">Register <i className="icon-circle-right2 position-right"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default RegisterForm
```

Signup passport strategy

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = function(passport){

    passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {
            console.log("In Signup");
            findOrCreateUser = function(){
                // find a user in Mongo with provided username
                User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, function(err, user) {
                    // In case of any error, return using the done method
                    if (err){
                        console.log('Error in SignUp: '+err);
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    // already exists
                    if (user) {
                        console.log('User already exists with username: '+username);
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message','User Already Exists'));
                    } else {
                        // if there is no user with that email
                        // create the user
                        var newUser = new User();

                        // set the user's local credentials
                        newUser.username = username;
                        newUser.password = createHash(password);
                        newUser.email = req.param('email');
                        newUser.firstName = "firstName";
                        newUser.lastName = "lastName";

                        // save the user
                        newUser.save(function(err) {
                            if (err){
                                console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);  
                                throw err;  
                            }
                            console.log('User Registration succesful');    
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }
                });
            };
            // Delay the execution of findOrCreateUser and execute the method
            // in the next tick of the event loop
            process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
        })
    );

    // Generates hash using bCrypt
    var createHash = function(password){
        return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10));
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

The issue appears to be due to the presence of the proxy. The form submit works if I directly call the nodejs backend API which is running on a different port (by allowing CORS) and remove the proxy. If I insert the proxy, and make the form point to the weback dev server, then form submit does not call the my nodeJS API. However, proxying works with curl and POSTMAN. Weird how curl works and form submit doesn't. Any pointers here will be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by cannot post?  What error do you get?

Comment: It's worth checking your Express log to see what's happening. It's possible you're missing the right body parser for the Content-Type of the incoming POST.

Comment: Also your form action is hitting an endpoint called /test. I don't see that exposed anywhere in your node app.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I get the following error:
Cannot POST /signup

/test is a typo here, my code correctly says /signup. I edited above to /signup and that is not the issue.

Comment: @tadman as you can see in the code, the enctype for the form is kept as default. The nodejs code has bodyparser for urlencoded. The logs don't show any error.

Comment: Are you sure that's how it's coming through? It's worth checking your Network Inspector and/or JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: I added encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in the form, still get the same error.

Comment: Moreover, I replaced the /signup route with a test route. I changed the "action" field in form to "/test" :
app.post("/test", function (req,res) {
      console.log("Hit test APII");
});
As you can see, I do not use req.body at all, just console.log and yet I get the same error.

Comment: @tadman Also worth noting is that I am proxying requests from webpack dev server to my nodejs server - I updated the first few lines of my question with this info. Could that be causing issues?

Comment: That's a possibility, but it seems odd that `curl` works and your web version doesn't. As a test, can you get it to work with either a) a plain web form minus React, or b) using plain jQuery `$.ajax`?

Comment: @tadman The form submit works if I directly call the nodejs backend API which is running on a different port (by allowing CORS) and remove the proxy. If I insert the proxy, and make the form point to the weback dev server, then form submit does not call the my nodeJS API. However, proxying works with curl and POSTMAN. Weird how curl works and form submit doesn't. Any pointers here will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

try to clear browser cache . if you are using chrome

1. go to `settings`
2. type `cache` in search
3. browse to bottom and clear cache .
   if it doesnt solve the problem please write back

Comment: Clearing cache doesn't help

Comment: This isn't really a solution. It can solve some problems, but using it as a go-to ritual is akin to witchcraft.